# How to import data from Google Cloud Platform (BigQuery/Cloud SQL) into R?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, jupyter-lab

I know there is API for Python to import data from GCP BigQuery into Jupyter Notebook. I am looking for way to import data from GCP (whether Cloud SQL or BigQuery) into R directly. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery? There are many related blog posts on https://reddit.com/r/bigquery too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look into: ["Use R with BigQuery"](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery). That page describes how to load data from BigQuery into an R data frame, using the `bigrquery R package`. Also to this ["bigrquery"](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/) doc.

Also, as mentioned in the comments: it worth to take a look in to this [github](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) There are many related blog posts on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/). too

Comment: ok, thanks. I installed bigrquery in R and use it to interact with BigQuery.